# mechanism of IP alias

Tags: linux, networking, ip

I have just learned that Linux can do so called `ip alias.

How can one NIC have two IPs at the same time? IP addresses must be identified by MAC address using ARP in general, I think. So, I'm confused that Linux can respond with the same MAC for two different IP requests by ARP, but I'm not sure.

Is this guess right?

Comment: See some of the reference links to the accepted answer here: http://serverfault.com/questions/312221/can-a-single-network-card-have-2-ip-addresses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ARP requests are the question "Who has the address ?" The fact that the same interface answers to a bunch of different addresses is no big deal.